# Expection Maximization - on observation count in Coin toss example

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, nlp, expectation-maximization

I can see many examples related to EXPECTATION-MAXIMIZATION algorithm.

Few links are

[Expectation Maximization coin toss examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513792/expectation-maximization-coin-toss-examples)
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81004/how-does-expectation-maximization-work-in-coin-flipping-problem
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25111/how-does-expectation-maximization-work
http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v26/n8/full/nbt1406.html?pagewanted=all

In all cases, we have set of hidden sources (typically coins ).. and set of observations ( typically set of coin tossing).

For example
SRC = { Coin-1, Coin-2 }
OBSERVATIONS ARE 
{ HTH, SRC1 }, 
{ THH, SRC2 }, 
{ HHH, SRC3 }, 
{ HTH, SRC4 }, 
{ HTT, SRC5 }
here we pick a coin(unobserved,SRC1) and toss three times(observed, HTH).

My Question is , If I make a observation as a single coin toss,like
{ H, SRC1 }, 
{ T, SRC2 }, 
{ H, SRC3 }, 
{ H, SRC4 }, 
{ H, SRC5 }
Will EM work for this case ?    
If so, What will be result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. I am including a derivation below (but this is not really appropriate for stackoverflow):

[image]
[image]